# How do I know if blade fits the miter saw?

Tags: saw, miter

I just got my first miter saw (ryobi 15 Amp 12 in. Sliding Miter Saw with Laser).

I want to buy this diablo blade [http://www.amazon.com/D1280X-Diablo-12-Inch-Crosscutting-1-Inch/dp/B00008WQ35/ref=sr_1_4?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1464224602&sr=1-4&keywords=diablo+12+inch+miter+saw+blade](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00008WQ35).

How do I know if it fits my miter saw? Besides size and arbor, what else do I need to check from the size perspective?

Comment: Those are what matters, from a simple fit point of view. Other factors like kerf  and teeth and so on will affect how smoothly it cuts for your saw and your tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diameter is important, as that's the maximum size blade that will physically fit in the saw.  The arbor size is important, because that's the size hole that will fit on the saws mandrel. If either of these sizes are wrong, the blade simply will not fit on the saw.

The thickness of the blade doesn't typically matter, as far as fitting on the machine. Unless you're talking about a dado stack, but you'd not be putting that on a miter saw anyway. The blade thickness, or kerf, only tells you how much material will be removed when cutting.

The number of teeth influences the speed of the cut, as well as the smoothness of the cut.  Generally, more teeth give a smoother cut.

Comment: Just looked it up 1" mandrel so it should work. +